# How to iterate on muliselected text in Word using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Using ctrl key and left mouse button I can select couple not connected parts of text in document.
How in VBA iterate on those selected parts?
I have to export each of them to different file.

When I have couple selection, the `Selection Object` reference only to last of them.

Comment: Please include the code you have so far

Comment: This is not possible - the Word object model provides no way to work with multiple, non-contiguous selections. Best you can do is apply a specific kind of formatting to your selection, then use Find to locate each and transfer the "hits" to a different file.